# Missing little red "x" in Eclipse explorer and problems view for Java source with compile errors?

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, warnings

The little red 'x' on my Java class files in the project explorer (or package explorer) are missing.  They were there...now they are gone.

This has happened before and usually a project clean, rebuild will do the trick.  Also I unchecked the box that says abort build if build path error occurs.

Any ideas?

Edit:  I am using the Maven M2Eclipse plugin.

Comment: You find the lack of errors to be an error itself?

Comment: I do!  The files have errors which become immediately apparent when opening the source code in an editor.  But no other view shows the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that in my particular case, I have a multi-module maven project.  Disabling support for nested modules and then re-enabling support for nested modules did the trick. Apparently I needed to give m2eclipse a kick in the pants.  What convinced me to do it was the fact that it was only Java Errors and Java Tasks that were the only problem markers not appearing -- and the Java Builder was missing from the list of builders.

Answer (score 2):

The X indicates a compile error in the file.

Your build process is fixing the errors somehow.

See: [eclipse manual](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-7.htm).

Comment: I should have stated that the files in question DO have compiler errors.  When I open then, I see the red "x" in the margin of the file...and the red squiggly underline of the problem area.  It just doesn't show the issue in the problems view, or any of the explorer views -- just in the editor.  The result is that I think everything is fine...run maven on the command line and watch the errors appear.  When I then go into the problem file...boom...I see the compiler errors inside the editor...but still not in the explorer.